# Generate elements automatically in the DOM

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a project in Angular in which I have generated a table to store the fields of the table that I get from the back. My problem is that if the table schema increases I have to add a column to the front table.
Is it possible to do this automatically?

This is my component.html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

What I want to do is write only one element and generate it as many times as fields I get, that is, if I get five elements generate a table with five fields, duplicate the ng-container, in this case. I don't know if this is possible

Comment: Do [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-dynamic-columns) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the column array binded with the table datasource.
Additionally, I suggest you should define columns at runtime in the HTML instead of defining them as a static template.

You can refer to the below example, which I just created:

**`app.component.html`:**

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addColumn()"> Add column </button>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

The **`app.component.ts`** file should perform the required operation updating the column array:

```
 import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

export interface SampleInterface {
  position: number | 0;
  name: string | '';
  third?: string | '';
  lastName?: string | '';
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: SampleInterface[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Test'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium'}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'position','third'];
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();
  data: SampleInterface[] = ELEMENT_DATA;

  constructor( private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef,){}
  addColumn() {
    const newColumn = 'lastName'
    this.displayedColumns.push(newColumn);
    this.columnsToDisplay= this.displayedColumns.slice();
    let newObject: SampleInterface = {
      position: 3,
      name: 'thridName',
      third: 'NewColumn',
      lastName:'Last'
    }
       this.data.push(newObject);
       this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
      }
    }
```

This is just an example, and you can work on updating the column array as per your requirements.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for and provide feedback accordingly.